# Finding limit of bounded sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose we have a sequence $\{\frac{b_n}{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and we know that $$
0 \leq \frac{b_n}{n}\leq 1 \text{ }\forall n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
What can we conclude about $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{b_n}{n}$?

My impression is that we can just say the following

"If $\exists \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{b_n}{n}$, then it should be equal to $L\in [0,1]$"

Comment: It doesn't diverge, because it is bounded. If you pick $b_n = \frac{n}{2}\left( (-1)^n+1 \right)$ the limit doesn't exist. If it does exist then you're right, why?

Comment: Your impression is correct.  But what is the significance of writing $0\le \frac{b_n}{n}\le 1$ rather than just $0\le a_n\le 1$?